# Bus from Mostar to Podgorica

Tags: public-transport, montenegro, bosnia, podgorica

I would like to take the bus from Mostar to Podgorica. Is there any? I can't find much info online.

I did find MontenegroHostel is running a shuttle service from Mostar to Kotor, but considering that I would leave from Podgorica Airport, I prefer take a bus from Mostar to Podgorica directly.

Comment: Have you seen this planner (http://www.busterminal.me/timetable)?  For next Tuesday, for example, it shows a bus leaving Podgorica at 1 in the afternoon and arriving in Mostar at 8.  Presumably the bus returns, though maybe not in a single trip to Podgorica, since no such trip is shown originating in Mostar.  I guess you'll have to transfer in Kotor or Herceg Novi.

Comment: At the end I took the bus from Mostar to Kotor instead, then Kotor to Podgorica. Kotor is worth staying for a few days for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think there are direct bus services from Mostar to Podgorica. There are  buses from Mostar to Budva once daily (5.23 hrs) and then from Budva to Podgorica every 20 minutes (1.32 hrs). See this website for more details:
http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Mostar/Podgorica

This link might be also useful: http://wikitravel.org/en/Mostar

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple buses a day operated by Jadran Ekspress Kotor from [Mostar to Podgorica for sale on the Montenegrin bus ticketing site BusTicket4.me](https://busticket4.me/MNE/1276-1121-132-0-0/0-1/Mostar-Podgorica/)